# MalformedInputException at every page requested

Tags: java, jsf, prettyfaces

I'm getting this exception for each requested page in my web application. As it doesn't point to any application code, it's hard to debug and check what is causing the problem.

Is it something I should worry? Is there any way to ignore this exception? It's worth saying that the pages are rendering fine.

Java 1.7.0_25, Apache Tomcat 7.0.27, Mojarra 2.1.13 and PrettyFaces 3.3.3 as a URL rewriter solution.

```
Sep 15, 2013 2:21:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:260)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:781)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ByteArrayWebOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayWebOutputStream.java:112)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.flushToWriter(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:162)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at br.com.tostring.weblibrary.filters.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I realized that this exception occurs only when I add the **jstl-1.1.0.jar** in the classpath to avoid `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config`. If I remove this jar, the `MalformedInputException` stops but the `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

MalformedInputException thrown when an input byte sequence is not legal for given charset, or an input character sequence is not a legal sixteen-bit Unicode sequence.

This is happening during view rendering, so I would guess that you have something in your Facelet/XHTML template, or elsewhere, that is attempting to write content of a different encoding to the output stream.

Do you use any sort of output stream modification extensions or configuration?

Comment: Hi @lincoln, I don't have any sort of output stream modification. The curious part is that it only happens at my production enviroment and doesn't happen in development (local) Tomcat.

Comment: Do you know if your production environment has a modified catalina.xml file? Not sure what would cause that difference.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the entire Tomcat folder from my server via FTP and I had started it locally. The exception is not been thrown in my instance.

Comment: I realized that this exception occurs only when I add the **jstl-1.1.0** in the classpath to avoid `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config`. If I remove this jar, the `MalformedInputException` stops but the `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown.

Comment: This looks familiar, but unfortunately I don't have a solution :/ https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime/issues/55